# Does the "diameter" in "bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere" actually mean "radius"?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, bmesh

I created a sphere using

```
bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere(bm, u_segments=32, v_segments=16, diameter=1)
```

but later I noticed the radius of the sphere was 1 grid. As the exact size of the sphere was very important to me, I decided to check if 1 grid side is actually 0.5 (with whatever unit), but I didn't find anything particular. Afterwards I use the GUI way i.e. SHIFT+A to create a standard sphere (which should mean the size aka radius is 1), and I found they were exactly the same size.... So my question is: does the *diameter* in *bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere* actually mean *radius*, or am I missing something here?

P.S. I tried searching in the documentation but didn't find anything regarding this, so I decided to post the question here. I hope it is nothing too stupid.

Comment: IIRC it was a diameter, and was changed to  a radius to  be more consistent, however the argument name was not changed, to avoid breaking scripts..  https://developer.blender.org/T52923

Comment: Cool! Thank you for your reply! I was trying create_cone and found the same situation so I was wondering if it was a universal thing.